# How can I find the relative difference (percentage) but two data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given two data frames `df1` and `df2`, I can get the absolute difference between them via:

```
df3 = df1.compare(df2)
```

How can I get the relative difference between them?

I initially thought [pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) could do the job, but this function seems unrelated, since it doesn't take a data frame as input.

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Do you want it cell by cell?  Like `(df2 - df1) * 100 / df1`?

Comment: @TimRoberts: Exactly so, but I haven't been able to do that using plain arithmetic operations (despite the fact that I can `compare` the frames, which means that they have identical structure). Any idea?

Comment: @TimRoberts: Your answer has ultimately led me to the simple solution `(abs(df1 - df2) / df2).fillna(0)`. I only needed to apply `astype('float128')` on each frame beforehand, since my frames consist of `Decimal` values, which throw on division by zero (in contract with `float` values which return +inf or -inf or nan). Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the shapes and dtypes are the same in both, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_1 = {"a": [2, 4, 0, 6, 44], "b": [5, 3, 65, 33, 4]}

data_2 = {"a": [100, 4, 33, 32, 55], "b": [12, 55, 34, 76, 2]}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_2)

cols = []
for i, col_a in enumerate(df_1.columns):
    col_c_pct_change = (df_2.iloc[:, i] - df_1[col_a]) * 100 / df_1[col_a]
    cols.append(col_c_pct_change)

df3 = pd.concat(cols, axis=1, keys=[s.name for s in cols])

# replace infs with 0 (or whatever you preferred value is)
df3 = df3.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan).fillna(0)
```

---

```
             a            b
0  4900.000000   140.000000
1     0.000000  1733.333333
2     0.000000   -47.692308
3   433.333333   130.303030
4    25.000000   -50.000000
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to keep the titles of the original data frames (which are identical in structure, so can use the titles of the first frame, for example). In addition to that, your suggestion fails on division by zero when `df_1[col_a] == 0`. Obviously, such division would imply infinite relative difference. True - except for when `df_1[col_a] == df_2[col_a] == 0`, in which case, the relative difference is 0%. Any idea how to work around these cases?

Comment: We expect numpy behaviour when using arithmetic operators on pandas series as in the example above. So this is handled via numpy using it's `inf` type and pandas storing this in the resulting series and eventually in the final dataframe. It's up to you how to handle this case - in my example above I'm replacing it with a nan and fillna to substitute for 0. Title is fstring interpolation to add the suffix. Removed this in the example above.

Comment: Then why not just use `(abs(df1 - df2) / df2).fillna(0)`?